# Why am I able to inject entityManager without defining persistence-unit?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am able to inject `EntityManager` in my Service class without defining any persistence-unit.

This is my configuration:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example"></jpa:repositories>
```

In my Service class:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

// THIS WORKS!
final Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Is it because of the jpa:repositories ?

Comment: You have an entityManagerFactory which should be the one creating the entityManager and using the datasource specified, thus the injection works. ```jpa:repositoies``` simply tells Spring which packages (and subpackages) to scan for classes extending ```Repository``` and register them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring ORM package's `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` class makes this possible. It uses [DefaultPersistenceUnitManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.html) class to build an instance of  [PersistenceUnitInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html) which can then be provided to [PersistenceProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html) class's [createContainerEntityManagerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html#createContainerEntityManagerFactory(javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo,%20java.util.Map)). Hibernate implements this interface so that Spring can create an instance of [EntityMangerFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html) class.

[DefaultPersistenceUnitManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.html) class is the one that creates a persistenceUnit called `default` and finds all the entity classes going through the classes on the classpath. Same information acquired from the `persistence.xml` has been taken in  with a alternative approach like this without having a physical persistence.xml file.

Finally Spring uses [JpaVendorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaVendorAdapter.html) configured to get the JPA provider- specific EntityManagerFactory instance.

Spring data JPA specific `<jpa:repositories base-package="...." />` or [@EnableJpaRepositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html) uses to scan all the beans annotated with @Repository to provide dynamic queries and other features. This is not an exhaustive explanation but you see how this "magic" happens.

You can find more on [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.2.0.RELEASE) or download the sources to explore more.